# How to allow GKE internal Pod to communicate through VPN to an internal IP in another VPC?

Tags: kubernetes, networking, google-kubernetes-engine, vpc

I have a GKE cluster (private one) with a NAT that I need to put in networking with a legacy VPC (in another GCP project).

I built a classic VPN between Project B (new) and Project A (old): all VM can talk to each other (`nc -vz` is my friend).

The GKE cluster inside Project B can talk with internal IP to all VMs on Project B.
I need to have some pods in this GKE able to talk to the private IP on the VPN inside the Project A.

We tried [this how to](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/ip-masquerade-agent#deploy-ip-masq-agent-deamonset) but it's still not working.

If you have an idea that works in my case I will buy you a beer ;) (location : Le Havre, Lille or Paris)

[Infra scheme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SciYd.png)

Comment: Hi Christopher! How is routing configured (static/dynamic)? Do you see the routes for the opposite side in each "routing table"? Did you check firewall rules?

Comment: Hello, 
The routing is configured in static mode

Comment: Did you see the schema i put "infra scheme" ?

Comment: I did see the diagram, yes, you shouldn't need the masquerading unless you have overlapping subnets between projects.

Comment: I would double check the firewall rules, routes and capture traffic on the nodes to see the traffic leaving and on the other side to make sure it isn't coming.

Comment: I think that issue can be on the Calico service. we cannot add a network route inside the gke cluster

Comment: Hey @ChristopherCanon, Can I help you with other information? If you think that my answer helped you, please consider accepting it by clicking the checkmark (✔️) on the left side under the vote arrows. Should change the color to green. I'd really appreciate it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is an option in GCP called “Shared VPC”, that in summary, allows the multiple projects’ interconnection within an organization, using a common Virtual Private Cloud. As it is specified in GCP’s documentation, an organization policy applies to all projects in the organization, so you need to follow these steps just once to restrict lien removal [Organization policies for Shared VPC](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/provisioning-shared-vpc#org-policies). Then you need to follow these steps to provision the Shared VPC:

-Go to the [Shared VPC page](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/provisioning-shared-vpc) in the Google Cloud Console.

-Log in as a Shared VPC Admin.

-Select the project you want to enable as a Shared VPC host project from the project picker.

-Click Set up Shared VPC.

-On the next page, click Save & continue under Enable host project.

-Under Select subnets, do one of the following:

a)Click Share all subnets (project-level permissions) if you need to share all current and future subnets in the VPC networks of the host project with service projects and Service Project Admins specified in the next steps.

b)Click Individual subnets (subnet-level permissions) if you need to selectively share subnets from the VPC networks of the host project with service projects and Service Project Admins. Then, select Subnets to share.

-Click Continue.

-The next screen is displayed.

-In Project names, specify the service projects to attach to the host project. Note that attaching service projects does not define any Service Project Admins; that is done in the next step.

-In the Select users by role section, add Service Project Admins. These users will be granted the IAM role of compute.networkUser for the shared subnets. Only Service Project Admins can create resources in the subnets of the Shared VPC host project.

-Click Save.

In the following URLs you are going to find some GCP’s official information such as a Shared VPC Overview [Shared VPC overview](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/shared-vpc) and all the process in detail to set a new Shared VPC up [Setting up Shared VPC](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/provisioning-shared-vpc#console_1).